# Почему запрос не доходит до контроллера?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Есть простой контроллер на вызов которого я получаю `404`.

> Type Status Report
>
> Message /users/
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showUsers(ModelMap model) {
        return "users_view";
    }
}
```

Дебагер не останавливается на методе `showUsers` при вопытке сделать запрос на `http://localhost:8080/users/` так что вероятно проблема с конфигурацией.

Это структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.pravvich" />

</beans>
```

В `web.xml` спринговый сервлет примаплен вот так:

```
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Process application servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему.

Comment: Странный url-pattern какой-то, может нужно укзаать `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не соответствует мэппинг в контроллере мэппингу в web.xml.
Ваш DispatcherServlet обрабатывает все запросы оканчивающиеся на **.do**, в то время как контроллер UserController ожидает получить **/users**, который не оканчивается на **.do**.

Вам следует

- добавить .do в значение value:

  ```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/users.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String showUsers(ModelMap model) {
         return "users_view";
     }
  ```
- либо удалить расширение .do из **url-pattern** в **web.xml**

Советую прочесть как происходит обработка запросов в DispatcherServlet.